# How do you pass the MethodChannel Result to a new Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

fellow Flutter enthusiasts, pros, and future friends. I've been really banging my head from trying to pass the MethodChannel.Result from the MainActivity to a new activity (to handle the result handler after performing some work there).

In iOS, I've stuffed the FlutterResult into a struct with other pertinent values and passed that into a new ViewController, and have been successfully running the result handler from there.

How do I go about doing so in Android? Since the result isn't serializable I can't add it as an extra in an intent.

In my MainActivity, I'm running 'setMethodCallHandler', and in the proper call.method case, I'm creating a new intent and starting it. I'm successful adding in and pulling out String values in the new activity but it's that Flutter Result that I'm needing to pass over.

What is the recommended way to achieve this? Am I going about it the wrong way?

I ask if I'm doing it incorrectly because when I finish() this new activity, there is a half-second black screen that takes over the screen when the activity is dismissed.

Not sure if it matters, but I'm writing in Kotlin. I would be happy to hear any Java recommendations though.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I am getting same issue in IOS can you please add ios code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a little bit more context about what exactly you're doing in the new activity, it's a little bit hard to tell why you'd be getting a black screen. Theoretically, the flutter activity should still be running and should show up when you finish the new activity - unless you're doing something blocking on the UI thread.

However, for passing the `result` - what you want to be doing is to keep a reference to the `result` handler wherever you're receiving the message from flutter, and making use of android's `startActivityForResult` method. See the android docs on [getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result). Your 'worker' activity should do whatever it needs to do, then pass the result back by calling `setResult` before finish. The data you pass back must be serializable.

There is a slight added wrinkle - you're not necessarily working with your own activity here (if you're writing a plugin anyways). If that's the case, you'll need to implement `ActivityResultListener` and call `registrar.addActivityResultListener` in your plugin's `registerWith` function. If you're just doing this in an app, you can simply override `onActivityResult` - just make sure to call super or you might break other flutter plugins.

There is another possible solution to this, with various levels of hacky-ness depending on how in-depth you want to be. The solution is to simply use a Singleton or Global to store what you need between activities. *For anyone out there who's reading this - I don't endorse doing this, I'm just providing an alternative*. There are caveats to go with this - among them is that globals and to a lesser extent singletons are seen to be a bad idea for many reasons, among them code maintainability. If you absolutely must go down this route, I suggest using a Registry pattern rather than a simple singleton - i.e. you create a key that is serializable and store the `Result` in essentially a global/singleton map using the key, pass the key to the new activity, then in the new activity retrieve the value with that key (and make sure to remove the object from the map).

Note that the global/singleton/registry option won't work properly if the app is stopped by android as the activity could be recreated from its intent, but the object in memory may not persist. Then again - the flutter callback won't persist anyways so that point might be moot anyways.

If you're still seeing the black screen after finishing the new activity, that sounds more like a bug or something to do with the implementation of your new activity than a flutter problem.

Comment: Thank you, Morgan. I am an iOS dev so I was unaware of the functions that you have mentioned! // On the black screen, I will have to find a device and test it out because right now I'm only working with the simulated Android device on the computer. Perhaps that's what's causing it? I'm not doing anything special. Just starting a new intent with two text views, with a FAB simply running 'finish()' once tapped. When the activity dismisses downwards, there is a black screen behind that lingers behind before the Flutter screen reappears.

Comment: I'll see if I can get a chance to reproduce that at some point (or if your app is open-source I can just give it a go =D). There are definitely thigns that don't work as well on the emulator as a real device though so hopefully that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Morgan, thank you again. Just wrote the code using 'startActivityForResult' and I was able to pass serialized data successfully back to the Flutter app. Also on a physical device, the finishing of the native activity isn't a black screen that holds in the background awkwardly for milliseconds, but at the same time, the starting and finishing is a very ugly, not smooth, transition. Do you have any pointers on how to make transitions smoother here? I tried to override the 'finish' call and run the 'overridePendingTransition' function, but Android studio says the animation values are all private.